# Custom Picker appearing causes other views to rearrange

Tags: swift, swiftui, custom-view

Working with my Custom Picker to replicated Apple Picker but more personalized. My custom picker problem is when it appear the other views will get messed up i tried rearrange the order of these views still could not work. let me know if i can fix this problem without removing my custom picker.

[image: problem here]

```
 VStack {
            Text("\(selectedElement) is selected")
            if showPicker {
                CustomPicker(pickerData: ["Jonathan", "Cilan", "Wanda", "Depp", "Willy"], width: 400, selectedElement: $selectedElement)
            }
            Button("Show picker") {
                showPicker.toggle()
            }
            

        }

 struct CustomPicker: View {
 var pickerData: [String]
 var width: CGFloat
 @Binding var selectedElement: String
 var body: some View {
  ZStack {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          ForEach(pickerData, id: \.self) { data in
              Button {
                  selectedElement = data
              } label: {
                  Text("\(data)")
                      .padding(5)
                      .foregroundColor(.black)
              }
          }
      }
      .padding(.vertical, 5)
  }
  .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(.blue))
  .frame(width: width, height: 18.0 * CGFloat(pickerData.count))
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `CustomPicker` as `overlay` instead.

It will be treated similar to the elements inside a ZStack container, so the views under the overlay keep their original position.

```
 Button("Show picker") {
     showPicker.toggle()
 }
 .overlay {
    CustomerPicker() //this part
 }
```

Comment: love this magic trick =)